# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: node.js

first i had an error : Cannot use import statement outside a module which I was able to fix it by adding: "type": "module" to my package.json but now i'm getting a new error
Here is the error message
'''

^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:168:18)
at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:279:14)
at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:285:30)
at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:21)

Node.js v20.12.0